# How to make method calls async

Tags: asynchronous, c#-4.0, async-await, dataset

I have about 30 method calls (filling dataset). I want to make these calls parallel (asynchronous).
Please give me some code idea.Following are some of the calls.

```
 ds = (DS)dbManager.ExecuteDataSet(CommandType.StoredProcedure, Proc1, ds, tableNames);
 ds = (DS)dbManager.ExecuteDataSet(CommandType.StoredProcedure, Proc2, ds, tableNames);
 ds = (DS)dbManager.ExecuteDataSet(CommandType.StoredProcedure, Proc3, ds, tableNames);
 ds = (DS)dbManager.ExecuteDataSet(CommandType.StoredProcedure, Proc4, ds, tableNames);
 ds = (DS)dbManager.ExecuteDataSet(CommandType.StoredProcedure, Proc5, ds, tableNames);
 ds = (DS)dbManager.ExecuteDataSet(CommandType.StoredProcedure, Proc6, ds, tableNames);
 ds = (DS)dbManager.ExecuteDataSet(CommandType.StoredProcedure, Proc7, ds, tableNames);
 ds = (DS)dbManager.ExecuteDataSet(CommandType.StoredProcedure, Proc8, ds, tableNames);
```

Comment: "I want to make these calls parallel (asynchronous)" - "asynchronous" and "parallel" are related but different concepts. Often async in C# has nothing to do with introducing parallelism.

Comment: I think, that he means parallel - to speedup processing.

Comment: @Yuri: Yes, I'm sure - but I'm saying that it's worth being aware of the difference between these.

Comment: @ARC What you're using for database access is also going to drive your decision. Depending on how your `dbManager` is implemented, you may not have the option of running those calls in parallel.

Comment: And C# 4.0 knows nothing about async-await.

Comment: Thanks all for your response.Yes i want to speed up the processing by sending parallel calls without waiting the response of other call. I am using ADO.NET to contact DB.

Answer (score 1):

From my understanding your Proc1, proc2.. are procedure names. Just load them to the list and try this:

```
string[] procNames = {"Proc1","Proc2","Proc3","Proc4","Proc5"};
List<string> list =new List<string>();
foreach (var procName in procNames)
{
    list.Add(procName);
}
Parallel.ForEach(list, current =>
{
    ds = (DS)dbManager.ExecuteDataSet(CommandType.StoredProcedure, current, ds, tableNames);
});
```

Just be aware that this will NOT execute your procedures in any particular order.